# Track changes made in a record and get the version of the record at the given point of time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to track chages made in a record and able to get the any version of the record at given point of time.

#### Consider, I have the following contact table.

```
--------------------------
| contact                |
--------------------------
| id                     |
| name                   |
| phone                  |
| email                  |
| city                   |
| country                |
| create_by              |
| created_at             |
--------------------------
```

#### I want to achieve following things on the above table.

1. I want to track all the changes made in the records over the time.
2. I want to find the version of the record at the given point of time.
3. The original record should stay as it is (without any update).

For example,

**So, I have created following table to track all the changes.**

```
--------------------------
| contact_history        |
--------------------------
| contact_id             |
| field_name             |
| old_value              |
| new_value              |
| modified_by            |
| modified_at            |
--------------------------
```

**With this data model,**

1. To create a new contact record, we will create the record in the contact table.
2. To Update a record, we will create a new record in the contact_history record with the field name, new value, current time and who modified the record.

In this way I can able to track, what change was made and who made the change and the same time the original record will stay as it is without any change.

What I am trying to achieve is to find the version of all the contact records at a given point of time.

#### For example, consider the following record.

```
Contact table
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name  | phone   | email         | city | country | created_by | created_at              |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Steve | 1111111 | steve@abc.com | NY   | USA     | John       | 2019-04-01 13:17:49.417 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Each update will be created as a history record in the contact_history table.**

```
contact_history
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| contact_id | field_name | old_value     | new_value         | modified_at             | modified_by | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | email      | steve@abc.com | steve@changed.com | 2019-04-02 08:19:49.213 | Arnold      |
| 2          | city       | NY            | LA                | 2019-04-03 12:48:37.568 | John        |
| 3          | city       | LA            | SF                | 2019-04-04 25:25:19.715 | John        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**When I need the version of the contact record before 2019-04-02 I should able to get the following,**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name  | phone   | email         | city | country | created_by | created_at              |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Steve | 1111111 | steve@abc.com | NY   | USA     | John       | 2019-04-01 13:17:49.417 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**When I need the version of the contact record before 2019-04-03 I should able to get the following,**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name  | phone   | email             | city | country | created_by | created_at              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Steve | 1111111 | steve@changed.com | NY   | USA     | John       | 2019-04-01 13:17:49.417 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**When I wanted the latest version of the same record I should able to get,**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name  | phone   | email             | city | country | created_by | created_at              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Steve | 1111111 | steve@changed.com | SF   | USA     | John       | 2019-04-01 13:17:49.417 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The example is given for only one record. It can be applicable for multiple contact records.

How can I write a efficient query to achieve this in SQL Server.

Comment: The model you have chosen from your history table makes this type of thing absurdly difficult to put together. It is why I suggest people don't use an EAV style of audit table. I would instead recommend storing the whole row (or just the columns you care about auditing). You also don't need to store the "new" value. It will either be in the next audit row or the base table.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to how your change table is populated, it's going to be relatively hard to re-create the table's contents at a specific point in time. Does the actual table's values change when a change happens, or do the changes ONLY go into the change table?

Comment: @willaien, We won't update the actual table. Each change goes to the change table.

Comment: I don't have the time to create a representative example, but, you're probably going to find it easiest to UNPIVOT the table, UNION it with the change table, then PIVOT that whole dataset and get the max per column by changed/created date where the date is less than <point in time>.

Comment: @SeanLange, If we create the whole record again, how we identify what field was changed in the update? by comparing the previous change record?

Comment: @MelbinT You can have both types of audit tables.

Comment: Yes you would look at the previous update.

Comment: Carefully consider your actual requirements. Many, MANY, have taken this path of wanting to know every "version" of every row. Many discover, much later, that it doesn't really matter and that few ever look at this information (and even fewer find it useful). And as already mentioned, the EAV model is terribly complex and inefficient. Perhaps the only good point is that this "version at a point in time" info is often rarely used. Put your resources into features that are used the most.

Comment: @SMor, In my scenario, a record will go through multiple submissions. Approvers should be able to see the version of the record before each submission and will approve/reject the record. So, this requirement is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.   Use a TOP 1 query to get the most recent record before the date you want to filter on.

Unfortunately, due to the data model you've chosen to use, you'll need to do a TOP 1 subquery for every field in your result set that can be in your history table.

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT TOP 1 new_value ... WHERE field_name='Name' ... ) AS Name,
etc...
```

Comment: Changes happen in multiple fields, If I put TOP 1 query, I get the change for only one field.

Comment: His history table doesn't contain every row, it's instead more of an EAV table.

Comment: Yes, obviously due to the data model you've chosen to use, you'll need to do a TOP 1 subquery for every field in your result set that can be in your history table.